# Not able to access LWC decorator in Jest test JS file?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

```
import {createElement} from 'lwc';
import NewCmp from 'c/newCmp';


describe('c-new-cmp',() => {
    
    it('Test New cmp page', () => {
        const comp = createElement('c-new-cmp',{
            is: NewCmp,
        });
        document.body.appendChild(comp);
        // below line prints {}
        console.log('comp '+JSON.stringify(comp));  
        // below line prints undefined, I have isButtonVisible as a @track isButtonVisible in newCmp JS file
        console.log('comp '+comp.isButtonVisible);
            
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            
            // Not able to click on button
            comp.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-button[label="New"]').click();       
            

        }).then(()=> { 
           
        });
    })
    
})
```

**Please help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@track`-decorated variables aren't available inside your test.  You're expected to use a [black box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) approach to testing Lightning Web Components with Jest.  This means testing for the following "external" changes and effects:

- Changes in the DOM
- Changes to `@api`-decorated variables -- i.e. the variables that a parent component would need to access to support essential functionality
- Events your component dispatches
- Calls your component makes to subcomponents, imported methods, etc.

It means NOT testing for internal variable values or other internals within your component code.

If you need to log something to the console to debug the internals of your component during your test run, place the `console.log()` statement somewhere inside newCmp.js.  (Then, remember to remove it once you've worked out what's wrong.)

If you're feeling tempted to make `isButtonVisible` an `@api`-decorated variable just for the sake of being able to monitor its value inside a Jest test, resist the urge.  Ask yourself if there is any other way you can check that variable's value.  Usually that means checking for a DOM element that relies on the value.  In your case, where I assume you have some HTML code like this...

```html
<lightning-button if:true={isButtonVisible} label="New">
</lightning-button>
```

... I would imagine your test would use something like this to make sure your component is behaving the way you want:

```js
expect(
  comp.shadowRoot.querySelector(
    'lightning-button[label="New"]'
  )
).toBeTruthy(); // or .toBeFalsy(), depending on what you're testing
```

Final note: since `isButtonVisible` is probably a Boolean (not an object or array), using `@track` on it [won't have any effect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&type=5&release=224) in the first place.